# Can a private pilot create a Go Fund Me for charitable flights?

Tags: faa-regulations

I am a private pilot who flies for Pilots N Paws, and I want to create a go fund me to help support my Pilots N Paws flights. I am wondering if this is a violation of a FAR in regards to private pilots accepting compensation. The way I understand it is that the FAA does not want passengers paying unqualified pilots for flights that could potentially put the passengers at risk. In this scenario, there are no passengers, so I would assume it's acceptable for me to accept donations to help pay for these flights, but I just want to make sure. Just to be clear, the money from the go fund me is to help me, the pilot, pay for costs that are normally the responsibility of the pilot, such as crates, pet supplies, overnight hotels, cars, and other expenses associated with Pilots N Paws missions, not directly aircraft rental or fuel costs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the supplies, pet carriers and other costs for the upkeep and movement of the animals are fine, I think hotels and personal expenses may be a bit shaky.

Comment: Pretty positive there’s nothing in the CFRs about being reimbursed for charity work.  It’s definitely a gray area, but I’d advise that you keep meticulous expense records, and maintain as much separation between flight and administrative activities as possible.  (E.g. no pictures of airplanes on your go fund me page, just dogs…)

Comment: This is a question I would discuss with my local FSDO.

Comment: @GdD - I don’t see why hotels would be problem.  They have nothing to do with flight expenses. They’d exist even if OP drove the dogs instead of flying them.

Comment: It is true that hotel expenses would be incurred with driving @Jim, that doesn't mean that it wouldn't be seen as compensation by the FAA. The rules aren't always common sense.

Answer (score 1):

For any expenses you’d incur even if you were driving the pets instead of flying them, there should be no legal concerns at all.

Still, to be safe I’d keep excellent records (including scans/photos of receipts for everything) in case you ever have to prove you’re not violating 61.113.

Comment: You might be right, but if it was me I'd want to see some references to back that up.